# How to Improve Postgresql Slow Query

Tags: performance, postgresql, casting, union

I use Postgresql and here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_cdr
(
  uid serial NOT NULL,
  start_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  end_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  error_code smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 200,
  src_ip character varying(20),
  src_port smallint,
  dest_ip character varying(20),
  dest_port smallint,
  CONSTRAINT tbl_cdr_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX idx_tbl_cdr_date
  ON tbl_cdr
  USING btree
  ((start_time::date));

CREATE INDEX idx_tbl_cdr_end_time
  ON tbl_cdr
  USING btree
  (end_time);

CREATE INDEX idx_tbl_cdr_start_time
  ON tbl_cdr
  USING btree
  (start_time);
```

I have a query (postgresql) like:

```
(
select * 
from tbl_cdr  
where cast(start_time as date) in  
(
    select cast(start_time as date) as times 
    from tbl_cdr    
    where ( cast(start_time as date) >= '2016-04-30 22:00:00' and cast(start_time as date)  <= '2016-09-30 20:00:00' ) 
    and ( extract(hour from start_time) >= 22  and extract(hour from start_time) <= 24)      
    group by times  order by times  limit 5 
)   
and ( cast(start_time as date)  >= '2016-04-30 22:00:00'  and cast(start_time as date) <= '2016-09-30 20:00:00' )  
and ( extract(hour from start_time) >= 22  and extract(hour from start_time) <= 24)      
)  
UNION 
(
select *  
from tbl_cdr  
where cast(start_time as date) in  
(
    select cast(start_time as date) as times 
    from tbl_cdr    
    where ( cast(start_time as date) >= '2016-05-01 22:00:00' and cast(start_time as date)  <= '2016-09-30 20:00:00' ) 
    and ( extract(hour from start_time) >= 0  and extract(hour from start_time) < 20)      
    group by times  order by times  limit 5 
)   
and ( cast(start_time as date)  >= '2016-05-01 22:00:00'  and cast(start_time as date) <= '2016-09-30 20:00:00' )  
and ( extract(hour from start_time) >= 0  and extract(hour from start_time) < 20)      
) 
order by start_time asc
```

But it works very slow.

Do you have any advice for performance improvements?

I tried following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_tbl_cdr_date_casted ON tbl_cdr ( cast(start_time as date) );

CREATE INDEX idx_tbl_cdr_hour_casted ON tbl_cdr ( extract(hour from start_time) );
```

but these didnt help :)

Edit:
Query Explain:
[image]

Here is Analyze Output:

```
"Sort  (cost=311262.22..311333.53 rows=28524 width=179)"
"  Sort Key: tbl_cdr.start_time"
"  ->  Unique  (cost=305045.14..306613.96 rows=28524 width=179)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=305045.14..305116.45 rows=28524 width=179)"
"              Sort Key: tbl_cdr.uid, tbl_cdr.start_time, tbl_cdr.end_time, (...)"
"              ->  Append  (cost=75581.47..300396.88 rows=28524 width=179)"
"                    ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=75581.47..150055.82 rows=14262 width=179)"
"                          Hash Cond: ((tbl_cdr.start_time)::date = ((tbl_cdr_1.start_time)::date))"
"                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_cdr  (cost=608.80..74830.00 rows=28523 width=179)"
"                                Recheck Cond: ((date_part('hour'::text, start_time) >= 22::double precision) AND (date_part('hour'::text, start_time) <= 24::double precision))"
"                                Filter: (((start_time)::date >= '2016-04-30'::date) AND ((start_time)::date <= '2016-09-30'::date))"
"                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_tbl_cdr_hour_casted  (cost=0.00..601.67 rows=28523 width=0)"
"                                      Index Cond: ((date_part('hour'::text, start_time) >= 22::double precision) AND (date_part('hour'::text, start_time) <= 24::double precision))"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=74972.66..74972.66 rows=1 width=4)"
"                                ->  Limit  (cost=74972.64..74972.65 rows=1 width=8)"
"                                      ->  Sort  (cost=74972.64..74972.65 rows=1 width=8)"
"                                            Sort Key: ((tbl_cdr_1.start_time)::date)"
"                                            ->  HashAggregate  (cost=74972.62..74972.63 rows=1 width=8)"
"                                                  Group Key: (tbl_cdr_1.start_time)::date"
"                                                  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_cdr tbl_cdr_1  (cost=608.80..74901.31 rows=28523 width=8)"
"                                                        Recheck Cond: ((date_part('hour'::text, start_time) >= 22::double precision) AND (date_part('hour'::text, start_time) <= 24::double precision))"
"                                                        Filter: (((start_time)::date >= '2016-04-30'::date) AND ((start_time)::date <= '2016-09-30'::date))"
"                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_tbl_cdr_hour_casted  (cost=0.00..601.67 rows=28523 width=0)"
"                                                              Index Cond: ((date_part('hour'::text, start_time) >= 22::double precision) AND (date_part('hour'::text, start_time) <= 24::double precision))"
"                    ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=75581.47..150055.82 rows=14262 width=179)"
"                          Hash Cond: ((tbl_cdr_2.start_time)::date = ((tbl_cdr_3.start_time)::date))"
"                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_cdr tbl_cdr_2  (cost=608.80..74830.00 rows=28523 width=179)"
"                                Recheck Cond: ((date_part('hour'::text, start_time) >= 0::double precision) AND (date_part('hour'::text, start_time) < 20::double precision))"
"                                Filter: (((start_time)::date >= '2016-05-01'::date) AND ((start_time)::date <= '2016-09-30'::date))"
"                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_tbl_cdr_hour_casted  (cost=0.00..601.67 rows=28523 width=0)"
"                                      Index Cond: ((date_part('hour'::text, start_time) >= 0::double precision) AND (date_part('hour'::text, start_time) < 20::double precision))"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=74972.66..74972.66 rows=1 width=4)"
"                                ->  Limit  (cost=74972.64..74972.65 rows=1 width=8)"
"                                      ->  Sort  (cost=74972.64..74972.65 rows=1 width=8)"
"                                            Sort Key: ((tbl_cdr_3.start_time)::date)"
"                                            ->  HashAggregate  (cost=74972.62..74972.63 rows=1 width=8)"
"                                                  Group Key: (tbl_cdr_3.start_time)::date"
"                                                  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_cdr tbl_cdr_3  (cost=608.80..74901.31 rows=28523 width=8)"
"                                                        Recheck Cond: ((date_part('hour'::text, start_time) >= 0::double precision) AND (date_part('hour'::text, start_time) < 20::double precision))"
"                                                        Filter: (((start_time)::date >= '2016-05-01'::date) AND ((start_time)::date <= '2016-09-30'::date))"
"                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_tbl_cdr_hour_casted  (cost=0.00..601.67 rows=28523 width=0)"
"                                                              Index Cond: ((date_part('hour'::text, start_time) >= 0::double precision) AND (date_part('hour'::text, start_time) < 20::double precision))"
```

Comment: How do the 2 individual queries of the union perform if run them by themselves?

Comment: Good start posting the `create` statements. But as always with performance questions the `explain analyze` output is required.

Comment: Please [edit] your question add the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, verbose)`. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: First query is fast because of few data, but second one is slow @redneb

Comment: Pleas post the **text** output of `explain (analyze)`. The screen shot of the graphical plan is barely readable and hides too many details (unrelated, but: the parentheses around each select of the union are totally useless)

Comment: I added Analyz Output @a_horse_with_no_name